# Schoeps CMC6-u Mk41 or Schoeps CMIT 5u for FX recording

Tags: schoeps, sfx, shotgun

Hi,
I'm fairly new to FX recording and I'm looking for a good mic for excellent quality recordings.  I've done a decent amount of research and have narrowed it down to the Schoeps CMC6-u Mk41 or Schoeps CMIT 5u both for price and quality.  The only negatives I've found are the humidity issues which for my purposes won't really apply since I'm doing mainly indoor recording. Can anyone comment on either of these mics for FX recording?  The CMC6-u seems to be more versatile which as a musician is another plus.  Any reason to choose the CMIT?  Thanks!

Comment: I've owned a Schoeps MK4 and MK8 MS pair for over ten years, and never had a problem with humidity...they've recorded in the rain, waterfalls, waves at the beach without any hiccups. Go for the MK41 over the CMIT as a first purchase imho.

Answer (score 1):

An advantage of the MK41 is the ability to upgrade to an MS stereo setup by adding the MK8 to your rig. You can definitely do that with the CMIT5 as well, but its pickup pattern is narrower, so it may not work as well for an MS rig. If unwanted background noise is an issue with your FX recording, the the CMIT5 may be your best choice because of its increased directionality.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I've read the MK41 is pretty directional as well, hoping it's enough to cut out a decent amount of indoor background noise.  This was one of the main reasons I was looking at shotguns in the first place then stumbled on the mk41.

Answer (score 1):

If I could only have one mic for FX, I don't think I'd want it to be a shotgun.  Shotguns are great, but not for an all-purpose mic.  I'd much rather go with an MK4 or MK41.  The humidity issues on Schoeps mics are way over-hyped.  I doubt you'd have any problems except in the most extreme of conditions, at least based on reports I've heard from Schoeps owners.

Comment: Thanks Chuck, that was what I was thinking as well in terms of an all-purpose mic. My main concern with the MK41 was background noise in that I don't want any, or as little as possible, but it sounds like these mics are used pretty extensively for fx so will probably go that route.

Answer (score 0):

I'll start by saying, "+1 to Chuck's comments." Shotguns are great (the CMIT in particular...off-axis coloration is non-existent), but not the best polar pattern for versatility.

Shotguns are designed for use over a distance. Close miking tends to be the best way to capture clean recordings (high source to ambient ratios), but it's typically a bad idea with shotguns. If there's any possibility that your sound source is going to move, you need to pull a shotgun back a little to make sure you don't get unwanted attenuation of the source should it begin to exit the pickup angle. That means you're allowing more "space" for noise/unwanted ambient sounds to get into your recording (lowering the source to ambient ratio). A cardioid or hyper-cardioid can be placed closer to the source with less fear.

I know people who use omni-directional mics, ridiculously close to a sound source, to great effect. It's all in the placement.

Comment: Great info Shaun thanks. I didn't know that prior to reading this post.  Sounds like the MK41 is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Depends entirely on what FX you are recording. IMHO if you are looking at these types of mics for FX then budget isn't an issue for you. What I would say is that these mics will give you an awesome quality recording whichever one you pick.

Please bear in mind though, that some FX recording isn't done under controlled conditions and you may just find that for some tasks, the conditions you end up recording in - and the sound sources you record - may not be too healthy for the actual microphone itself. Consequently, you might want to consider something a little less expensive for some of the more hazardous or dangerous sound sources - which you will inevitably come across.

Additionally, consider dynamic mics for some high SPL work rather than condensor. Even with a pad, you will find that the dynamics give you a better result in the high SPL region.

Consider a range of mics. I fear you are starting at the high-end possibly without experiencing the range of quality you can get with lower-end mics. Don't get me wrong - I have 3 MK41's myself - I just tend to use other mics for a lot of the FX work and the 41's when I am in more controlled conditions.